# Find a string between 2 strings with a match

Tags: php, string

My string is something like this

```
file: "http://website.com/640/image.jpg", type: 'jpg', quality: "640"
```

I want to grab the link in this 2 different ways if possible

if its between **"** and **"** and matches **640** inside the link

or if its between **file: "** and **", type: 'jpg', quality: "640**

how can I do this with some function like preg_match() or other?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like JSON format without the { and }.

Try:

```
$str = '{' . $str . '}';
json_decode($str);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Edit:

To extract the URL:

```
$pos = strpos($str, '"', 0);
$start = $pos + 1;

$pos = strpos($str, '"', $start);
$end = $pos - 1;

$url = substr($pos, $start, ($end - $start) - 1);
```

Comment: I have edited my code, there's probably a better way with regular expressions though.